# Concatenar em loop com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, seletores

Preciso concatenar com jQuery todos os valores de inputs que tenham classes que se iniciam por "item_".
Estou usando a função abaixo mas não deu certo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button.vai').click(function(){
  var item = $("input[class^='item_']").val();
   for(i=0,i<item.length,i++) {
    item += item + "#";
   }
  $(".result").val(item);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><button class="vai">concatena tudo!</button></p>

<input type="text" class="item_1" value="valor1"><br>
<input type="text" class="item_2" value="valor2"><br>
<input type="text" class="item_3" value="valor3"><br>
<input type="text" class="item_4" value="valor4"><br>
<input type="text" class="itemfalso" value="valor5"><br>
<p><input type="text" class="result" value=""></p>
```

Espero obter um resultado como o seguinte que está entre aspas: "valor1#valor2#valor3#valor4". Independentemente da "extensão" que eu colocar em item_**minhaextensão** e da quantidade de campos que contenha essa classe eu quero concatenar seus valores para formar uma só string.

Comment: Cara, essa linha `var item = $("input[class^='item_']").val();` eu suspeito que tu tenha feito para pegar todos valores dos `inputs` onde `class = item_X`. Mas ele só está pegando o valor da primeira `class`.

Comment: Obrigado Jeferson, vou rever o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode manter seu seletor como está e utilizar as funções `.map()` para gerar seu array dos valores, e a função `.join('#')` para concatenar as posições do array com a string `#` conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
$('button.vai').click(function () {

    var arrayValor = $("input[class^='item']").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join('#');

    $('.result').val(arrayValor);
});
```

Segue [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/sonzyemj/) =D

Comment: Perfeito Brunno, era o que eu precisava.